# How to filter users who have read more than 4 books?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset of user books ratings and would like to select only those users who have read more than 4 books and books that have been read by more than 4 users.

My data look like:

```
data.head()

    UserID  Rating  ISBN13  GoodreadsID     Title   Author
0   2111961     0   1592574289  1917    The Complete Idiot's Guide to Long Distance Re...   Seetha Narayan
1   2111961     0   1580087140  1918    The Long-Distance Relationship Survival Guide:...   Chris Bell
2   2111961     0   0972114807  1919    Long Distance Relationships: The Complete Guide     Gregory Guldner
3   2111961     0   006091565X  1047974     The Dance of Anger: A Woman's Guide to Changin...   Harriet Lerner
4   2102951     0   006091565X  1047974     The Dance of Anger: A Woman's Guide to Changin...   Harriet Lerner
```

I've tried:

```
data = data.groupby('UserID').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 5)
```

But not sure if that really works.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `new_df = data.groupby('UserID')['ISBN13'].count(); newdf[new_df.gt(4)]`?

Comment: @QuangHoang That select users having more than 4 books but how do I use it to filter original dataset?

Comment: `s = data.groupby('UserID')['ISBN13'].transform('count'); df[s]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **ISBN13** is the ID of the book, you can try

```
mask1 = data.groupby('UserID')['UserID'].transform('count') > 4
mask2 = data.groupby('ISBN13')['ISBN13'].transform('count') > 4

data.loc[mask1 & mask2]
```

Comment: Actually, the mas does not seem working. I did df = data.loc[mask1 & mask2] and than df.droupby('UserID')['ISBN13'].count().describe() and minimal values is 1.

Comment: Can you provide a data sample where does this happen? then I can test on my computer

Comment: Try this one, should be basicaly the same: https://www.kaggle.com/jirakst/bookcrossing
Thanks!

Comment: It is possible to have only one instance of a book read more than 4 times, because it possibly did not meet the user filter with more than 4 books read

Comment: If 5 users read the same book, but 4 users read only 1 book, this book will only enter the new DF if the last user who has read it has read more than 4 books

Comment: Oh, I see. So I need to repeat the step quite few times I guess to ensure no such cases are present. Is there a way how to do that in a cycle, so the approache is universal?

Comment: I don't know where you want to go. If you want books that have been read at least 4 times, use only mask2, but so you will get users who may have read only 1 single book

Comment: Yeah... I want books that have been read more than 4 times AND users who have read more than 4 books at the same time.

Comment: It makes sence but when I check it, it gives me that minimal occurance of a book or a user is 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for k,g in df.groupby('UserID'):
    if len(g)>=(4):
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df,g])
    else:
        pass
```

`new_df` is the dataframe with users who have read more than 4 books.

Answer (score 1):

Users who have read more than 4 books:

```
s = df.groupby('UserID')['ISBN13'].count()
u = s[s > 4].index
df[df['UserID'].isin(u)]
```

Books that have been read by more than 4 users:

```
s = df.groupby('ISBN13')['UserID'].count()
b = s[s > 4].index
df[df['ISBN13'].isin(b)]
```